# dropdown selection in HTML table cell, using selenium webdriver and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, html-table, webdriver, cell

My HTML table has a cell in 5th column that contain drop-down menu of values "1", "2" and "3";

so far I am at the point where I can get to that cell:

```
ICollection<IWebElement> table = driver.FindElements(By.Id("highVolumeSearchResults_group"));
List<IWebElement> elements = table.ToList();                
ICollection<IWebElement> cell_action = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//tbody/tr/td[5]"));
```

`Cell_action` - is a variable that contains drop down options/values "1", "2", "3").  I am not sure how to proceed, but I need to be able to select any value from the drop-down menu.
Can anybody  give me a hint?

The code behind it :

```
 </table>
      <table id="highVolumeSearchResults_group" class="highVolumeSearchResults">
      <thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td class="title letter" rowspan="1">W</td>
         <td>
            <a id="group-name-244" href="/Portal/Workgroup/Details?id=244">WorkGroup_Cats</a>
         </td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>12/28/2012 4:14:01 PM</td>
         <td>
           <select id="244" onchange="CommitAction(244, this.options[this.selectedIndex].value, this)">
              <option value="">------</option>
              <option value="edit">Edit Users</option>
              <option value="rename">Rename</option>
              <option value="delete">Delete</option>
           </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

the problem is the 'select id="244" ' part - is dinamically generated, so I sghould not use the id. I need to come up with DropdownBox option, but dont know how yet. I have also tried to continue with :

```
IWebElement cell_action1 = cell_action.First(); and then 
SelectElement DropDownBox_action = 
    new SelectElement(cell_action1.FindElement(
        By.XPath("//select[contains(, 'CommitAction')]")));
```

This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using `SelectElement` it's actually pretty easy:

```
var dropdown = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//tbody/tr/td[5]/select"));

var selectElement = new SelectElement(dropdown);

selectElement.SelectByValue("rename"); // or another value (ex: edit, delete)
```

---

#### Update

If you want to get the `<select>` elements that contain the string `"CommitAction"` in the `onchange` attribute, use this XPath expression: `"//select[contains(@onchange, 'CommitAction')]"`

Comment: If the answer provided a good solution, please accept it. It is important to also accept good answers. So far you got 7 questions and no accepted answer.